# How We use $Scope variable in Angular JS without declaring?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

can you explain how $Scope varibale works without declaring any place 
in angular JS?

Answer (score 2):

It is in fact declared. For example, when you make a controller, you pass in a `$scope` object. From the Angular [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) page:

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.username = 'World';

  $scope.sayHello = function() {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
  };
}]);
```

Note the `'$scope', function($scope)` - using Angular's dependency injection framework, you are injecting the `$scope` object in.

Comment: My question is when we make a function using parameter then when we call it we pass that parameter .It's law of any function but in angular JS when i am using that Controller ,i am not passing any parameter value from view ,then How $Scope value get

Answer (score 0):

It is getting injected by angular's dependency injector service.

> When you use the ng-controller to bind an controller to the view, a new ChildScope is created which prototypically inherts from the $rootScope.

$injector is name of the service being used for injection.

> $injector is used to retrieve object instances as defined by provider, instantiate types, invoke methods, and load modules.

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) is angular documentation of service.